# Package imported but not used even if I clearly used the package

Tags: go

I don't understand why importing local package in GO is such a pita. They often throw the "package imported but not used" error even if I clearly use the package in that same file! And then the code where I use it throws an "undeclared name" error as if I haven't imported it but somehow you can't identify.

Anyone can fix my problem? This isn't the first this happened to me. A lot of times I just play around until it works, but now it becomes very annoying.

```golang
// go.mod

module final-project
```

```golang
// cmd/main.go

import (
    "final-project/infra"
    "final-project/handler"
)

func main() {
    db := config.DBInit()
    inDB := &handler.CommentHandler{DB: db}
}
```

```
// infra/config.go
package infra

import (
    "fmt"

    "final-project/entity"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)


func DBInit() *gorm.DB {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to database")
    }

    fmt.Println("Database connected")

    db.AutoMigrate(structs.Comment{})
    return db
}
```

```
// handler/comments.go
package handler

import "net/http"

type CommentHandler struct{
    ///
}

func (u CommentHandler) Create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ///
}
```

```
// entity/structs.go
package entity

import "time"

type Comment struct {
    ID uint
    Message   string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```

This happends in all of lines of code where I try to import the any package from "final-project" module. And because of this, all codes where I used the package like `db := config.DBInit()` (imported from final-project/infra), `db.AutoMigrate(structs.Comment{})` (imported from final-project/entity), etc throw the `undeclared name` errors (even if, as you can see, I've tried to import it). Why do my codes somehow not identify the imports? Anyone can help me?

Comment: you are using it wrong even though you have imported correctly function inside package are access through package name not by file name as in your code you are accessing `config.DBInit()` instead `infra.DBInit()` hear config is file not package the same goes for other import `structs.Comment{}` here struct is file name not package it should be `entity.Comment{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing it wrong it should not be file name

```
db := config.DBInit()
```

Instead it should be package name

```
db := infra.DBInit()
```

The same goes for `structs.Comment{}` which should be `entity.Comment{}`